# Java Vs Spark to Consume Kafka Messages

Tags: java, apache-spark, cassandra, apache-kafka, spark-streaming

I am currently evoluating below two ways to consume and process the JSON messages from Kafka Broker

1. Kafka -> Java Program -> Cassandra
2. Kafka -> Spark Program -> Cassandra

Mean while if any of you have done this before, can you please share your one or two major observations ?

I will share mine once I am done with my experiment.

Thank you

Comment: Some would say that you can do everything with an HashMap and good GC tuning. I'm a spark fan. I believe that this question is off topic for that matter. It's quite broad and also option based for me. I'm voting to close it.

Comment: Hi @eliasah I understand this question is high-level, but I assume everybody who is freshly starting with the Spark implementation/learning might encounter same doubts, if possible please try to share some of your knowledge else please let others help me/any new spark learner by keeping the question Open. thank you.

Comment: I believe benchmarking is good way to settle on what to choose.

Comment: Hi @eliasah, thanks for the idea, i did bench marking and found that Spark suites better for our requirements.

Comment: Thanks for sharing your feedback !

Answer (score 2):

If you need the processing of your JSON messages to:

- Scale horizontally and
- Abstract away the difficulties of distributed/parallel processing

then a Spark program is the right choice. If it's a simple program that will never have large data volumes, a java program is the right choice.

Comment: Hi Thank you for the answer. could you please elaborate little bit more about parallel processing in terms of number of threads in case of Java and Spark ? I am assuming in case of Java only one thread process all the messages, where in case of Spark streaming, as many JVMs as executors will be launched and process the data parallel, can you please correct if my understanding is correct - thank you.

Comment: Correct, you can specify how many you want to process the data. Spark is far easier than writing thread-safe parallel processing code yourself.